# Convert text file to Word docx

Tags: vba, batch-file, docx

I need VBA code that will convert a text file (.txt) to a MS Word document (.docx).  Does anyone have code to accomplish this?  I have many text files within a directory and would like to batch convert them to docx files within the same directory or a VBA created directory using the same directory name with "converted" added to the directory name. I have upwards of 800 txt files to be converted.

Thank you,
Nelson

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VBA script / macro in Excel by recording the steps to import the text file and save it to an Excel (xls, xlsx) file. I have done this with Excel, but Word has similar recording / macro functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4755) I've created a script that does exactly the opposite.Here's a reworked one that creates a `docx` from `txt` (it is a vbscript/batch hybrid and needs to be saves as a `.bat`)  **NEED ADMIN PERMISSIONS** (to start invisible word mainly) :

```
'>nul 2>&1|| @copy /Y "%windir%\System32\doskey.exe" "'.exe" >nul
'&&@echo off && cls &&goto :end_vbs

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = FALSE

'Open txt for reading
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0),false)

'wdFormatText 2
'wdFormatUnicodeText 7
'wdFormatDocumentDefault 16
'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839952.aspx



WordDoc.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1) ,16 
WordDoc.Close()
WScript.Quit

:end_vbs

'& if "%~1" equ "-help" echo %~n0 text_document [ destination ]
'& if "%~1" equ "" echo txt document not given & exit /b 1
'& if not exist "%~f1" echo txt document does not exist & exit /b 2
'& if "%~2" equ "" ( set "save_as=%~dpn1.docx") else ( set "save_as=%~2")
'& if  exist "%~f2" del /s /q "%~f2"
'& for  %%# in ("%save_as%") do set "save_as=%%~dpn#"
'& taskkill /im winword* /f >nul 2>&1
'& cscript /nologo /E:vbscript %~f0 "%~f1" "%save_as%" 
'& pause
'& rem del /q '.exe
```

May be I should create a jscript/bat hybrid as the code will be more convenient...
Anyway this accepts 2 arguments one for the `.txt` file and one for the `.docx` desination but the txt file will stay undeleted. You can use this to iterate your txt files convert and delete them

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know much about programming so I don't know how to use this code.  I copied it directly to a .bat file but it doesn't seem to do anything except flash a DOS window on the screen and then stop.  How do I go about using this code?  Sorry to be such a neophyte.

Comment: @ntman2 - First you can add a pause at the end to see what happens , or call it from command prompt.The script needs to arguments - path to the `txt` and the path to the `docx` you want to create. lets say it's saved as `txt2docx.bat`.To convert `test.txt` to `test.docx` you need to call it from command prompt like this : `c:\dir>txt2docx.bat "c:\dir\test.txt" "c:\res\test.docx"`